# AWStats 7 download - 206 Hits

Tags: awstats

AWStats 7 shows two rows under download: hits and now 206 hits.

I understand that 206 are partial downloads (e.g. when using a download manager).

Here are some sample results:

- fileA.pdf - 23 hits, 38 206 hits
- fileB.pdf - 5 hits, 4 206 hits
- fileC.pdf - 1 hit, 0 206 hits

What I don't understand is if the file was downloaded the sum of both hits, or just the hits:
e.g. was fileA.pdf downloaded 23 times, or 61 times?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It was completely downloaded 23 times and 38 times it was only partially downloaded (user cancelled or network disconnected) So you could say that a download was attempted 61 times but only fully completed 23 of those times.

Comment: I believe that some of those 23 hits could have been interrupted, and some of those 38 "206 hits" could be resumed downloads from previously interrupted transfers. In summary, imho the actual number is impossible to tell from those figures.